# synchronize two horizontal scroll view android

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

i have two horizontal scroll views each containing a linear layout item under it. how is it possible to synchronize the scroll, when either of it is  scrolled, the other is also automatically scrolled. any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is on the onTouch of the first Horizontal Scroll view, record the X position that it started with for an action of Down.  Then when you have an action of Move, record the change in the X position.  Then you can call the second horizontal scroll view's scrollBy (deltaX, 0).  On an action of Up or Cancel, make sure to reset your state variables.

I've done this with a List View scrolling a vertical scroll, just using Y positions instead of X.  Here is my code to accomplish this.  The concurrentScroller is my vertical view.

```
if(concurrentScroller != null) {
            int deltaY = (int) (startTouchConcurrentY - ev.getY());
            startTouchConcurrentY = ev.getY();
            concurrentScroller.scrollBy(0, deltaY);                             
        }
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work when flipping, the first view keeps going while as the second just move an deltaY movement. :(

Comment: any idea about this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848391/how-do-i-synchronize-scrollview-positions-of-dynamic-horizontal-scroll-views-ins

Answer (score 1):

I would implement `onScrollListener` for each of the views to call `scrollTo` on the other.

Comment: Which views? There is no   `onScrollListener` method for `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: ```scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener(){...});```

Comment: Hi Alexandru, any idea about this one ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58848391/how-do-i-synchronize-scrollview-positions-of-dynamic-horizontal-scroll-views-ins